# custom attr selector using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="placeholdSlots">
    <div sort-helper="1"></div>
</div>
```

How select the div using sort-helper custom attr? I know attr('sort-helper') can only get the value.

Comment: You should start custom attributes with `data-` prefix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('div[sort-helper]');`

or in vanillaJS

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[sort-helper]');
```

Anyway I would suggest to use a `data-*` attribute instead, e.g.

```
<div data-sort-helper="1"></div>
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using data-?

Comment: the code will be valid with HTML5 doctype, while `sort-helper` is an invalid attribute

Comment: if it's `data-sort-helper1` I tried $('div[data-sort-helper]' + x) why is it not selected?

Comment: `$('div[data-sort-helper' + x +']')`

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery **[attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** selector

```js
alert($('div[sort-helper="1"]').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholdSlots">
    <div sort-helper="1">abc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I have multiple tag? select 1 by 1?

Comment: use `each()` method to iterate

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is not the only way. You can use direct Javascript, like this:

- Retrieving the firt div with an attribute called `sort-helper`

  `var elem = document.querySelector("[sort-helper]");`
- Retrieving all divs with an attribute called `sort-helper`

  `var list = document.querySelectorAll("[sort-helper]");`

This is faster that `jQuery` because it is native code. And it is now [cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) (for modern browsers ;-)).